# Angle between vectors $a$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Given $a = (4,5,-3)$ and $b = -i + 2 j + k$.

I am asked to measure the angle between $a - b$ and $-j - k$.
I know how to get the $a-b$ angle but I don't understand what to do for the $-j-k$ angle.

Am I supposed to take just  $a= (5,-3)$ and $b=(2,1)$ and use those?

Comment: Please show us how you found the $a-b$ angle.

Comment: Its not the $a-b$ angle or $-j-k$ angle. We are asked to find the angle between the two vectors $a-b$ and $-j-k$

Comment: had to roll this question back, not sure why the OP decided to vandalize own question

Comment: @jimjim bumping the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first vector is $\vec x = \vec a - \vec b = (5,3,-4)$.

The second vector $\vec y =  -\textbf{j} - \textbf{k} = 0\textbf{i} -1\textbf{j} - 1\textbf{k}=(0,-1,-1)$

Use the dot product. $\vec x \cdot \vec y = |\vec x||\vec y| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle you need to find.

This gives you $(5)(0)+ (3)(-1) +(-4)(-1) = \sqrt{5^2 + 3^2 + (-4)^2} \sqrt{0^2 + (-1)^2 + (-1)^2} \cos \theta$ which yields $\theta = \arccos \frac 1{10} \approx 84.26^{\circ}$